# What are low activity, medium activity and high activity

Tags: seo, analytics, statistics

I received stats for a website (page views, bounce rate, etc), I can't understand what some of the columns mean.

Low activity
Medium activity
High activity

The numbers are biggest in the "Low activity" column
The numbers are lowest in the "High activity" column

Any idea?

Here's a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Flipke/cJMe3/

Comment: Which stats package is this and can you show us an example?

Comment: The stats are from sitemetrics, here's a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Flipke/cJMe3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these are very generic statistics determined by some sort of unknown logic:

The column after the `Activity` is `Pages/v` which I assume is "Pages Per Visit (average).
The low/medium/high activity titles are probably determined by the number of pages a visitor browses in one session. This is where the "unknown logic" comes in. These numbers likely mean that there were "xyz" visitors who visited more than `high logic` pages, "rst" visitors who saw between `low and high logic` and then "abc" visitors who went to fewer than `low logic`.

In fact, I'm almost certain of that. If you look into the company or software that generates those statistics, perhaps they will provide information as to exactly what "High, Med, and Low" activities are.

Maybe beyond number of pages visited, it accounts for time spent on pages as well.

Comment: Thanks for this ! Unfortunately I don't have access to the informations you talked about. But you made it much more clear for me. Thank you sir.